# Do we need knowledge, defined as "Justified, True Belief", at all?

Tags: epistemology

The [Justified, True Belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#KnowJustTrueBeli) account of knowledge is problematic and none of the solutions proposed seems to solve all possible [Gettier problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem) (at least, that's what I have come to believe).

Do we need truth in an account of knowledge? Can it be merely defined as rational belief or justified belief?

I say this, because access to truth seems very puzzling. How should I "know" I have reached truth? Even science posit [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) as his main criteria, which means we do not really know something; we just have some kind of belief about how things really are, justified by the lack of evidence to the contrary.

Does epistemology have to concern itself with justified belief rather than with justified **true** belief? Is the truth condition chimerical?

Comment: There are distinct TYPES of truth.  In science, truth requires physical evidence & this implies awareness once you have the physical evidence. In this way if I an unaware of x the scientific answer is i do not know x.  This differs in epistemology because I don't need physical proofs.  Objective truths are distinct from the science context of the same word TRUTH. If I say something like x is true i mean that x is objectively true. This implies x is impossible to be false or my initial claim about x is mistaken. Truth preceeds human awareness. X doesn't suddenly come true & was unknown prior.

Comment: Removing "truth" from the analysis of knowledge is also more natural from the historical perspective, that we now know "better" seems rather moot to what Aristotle's or Archimedes's circumstances. However, one of the semantic functions of "know" seems to be to privilege *today's* view. A systematic proposal for doing it without identifying it with truth, or "mostly" truth is called  "pragmatic encroachment", it is briefly described in the linked SEP article. But it goes against the usual linguistic intuitions that JTB attempts to capture.

Comment: @Conifold :  linguistic intuition may be misleading. Afterall, JTB attempts to capture knowledge as binary, whereas it can be more suitable a probabilistic definition of knowledge (Bayesian). And that's all we need about knowledge: justification and belief.

Comment: It is not clear to me that these days JTB actually attempts to describe some "correct" notion of knowledge as such, although it was certainly Plato's original intention, so much as simply describe linguistic intuitions about the colloquial use of the word "know" in conjunction with equally naive use of the word "true". That is the impression I get from Gettier type discussions, just get an approximation of common use with good formal properties, and common use is not misleading about itself. Few take Platonist or Kantian idea of Knowledge seriously to care about anything beyond that.

Comment: Gettier cases show that J+T+B aren’t *jointly sufficient* for knowledge. Concluding from this that T isn’t *necessary* for knowledge, would simply be invalid: Winning the quarter- and semi-final of the World Cup are not jointly sufficient for winning the Cup; but winning the semi-final is still a necessary condition on winning the Cup. You can still claim that knowledge doesn’t imply truth; but the Gettier cases – or the failure of the JTB approach more generally – provide no support for this.

Comment: Also, the intuition that knowledge requires truth is pretty solid. “Jack knows that Jill is pregnant, but she isn’t” & “Jack falsely knows that Jill is pregnant” are *very* difficult to understand. Cf “Jack believes (with justification) that Jill is pregnant, but she isn’t” & “Jack falsely (but justifiedly) believes that Jill is pregnant”. Also, if there are any factive propositional attitudes, they plausibly imply knowledge: if Jack regrets p, we’d say that he knows p. If Jack only justifiedly believes p, or hopes it, he may not know. So, it looks like knowledge belongs in the factive camp.

Comment: @MarkOxford How do we access truth according to you?

Comment: The usual ways: thinking and looking (aka *a priori* and *a posteriori*, aka armchair and empirical investigation). To add two pre-emptive remarks: (1) If you think that truth is inaccessible (whatever that means), what are your beliefs and belief-forming processes aimed at? If fact, what do you believe when believing that p – if it’s not that p is true? How do you act on your belief that p – if it’s not acting as though p was true? (2) Even the Sceptic grants that our beliefs are true (that there is such a thing as true belief). She only denies that any of our (true) beliefs are knowledge.

Comment: @MarkOxford That is not my understanding of skeptics, unless "p is true" is just a deflationary turn of phrase for p itself. The traditional meaning of "true" was bound to the correspondence theory of truth, and skeptics were saying since ancient times that even if a belief of ours happened to be "true" we wouldn't be able to tell. From this point of view the T of JTB is a vacuous decoration, which in practice stands for "present consensus" or some such.

Comment: @conifold I should have stated (2) more carefully: the disagreement with the Sceptic isn’t over whether p is true, but over whether we know p. I mean, it’s not like the Sceptic claims that grass isn’t green / that it’s not true that grass is green. The claim is that we don’t know that grass is green. (But this doesn’t mean we suddenly have to suspend judgement about the colour of grass.) As for T being a vacuous decoration in JTB, I’m not so sure: even the Sceptic can hold that knowing p entails p’s truth. - I'm not sure I've addressed the points you were making.

Comment: @MarkOxford I guess I am not clear on what "p's truth" means. A skeptic, in principle, does not claim anything: grass appears green, sure, but who knows. If we can never know whether any particular p is true in any robust sense, as in "correspondence to reality" in some way, there is no point to using it, for defining knowledge or otherwise. Then there are of course anti-realists, who argue that the "correspondence" is, on reflection, unintelligible to begin with. So if knowing p entails its truth then either it takes God to know anything, or the "truth" of JTB is something very deflated.

Comment: @Conifold I feel that there are too many moving parts here. If you/the sceptic think that knowing p doesn’t entail p, aren’t you just talking past pretty much everyone in contemporary analytic philosophy? (If you’re making a point about ancient or non-analytic scepticism, I’m afraid I don’t know anything about that.) Also, if p being true isn’t a necessary condition on knowing p, what *are* the necessary conditions? Claiming that we don’t know p means there’s a necessary condition on knowing p that we don’t meet. So, the sceptic must name at least one necessary condition on knowing p.

Comment: @MarkOxford I feel that there is a disconnect between JTB and analytic epistemology. When Quine et al. say, for example, that all of our knowledge is future open and subject to revision they are saying that knowledge does not entail truth (whatever that is), at least on the colloquial meaning of the terms. In practice, knowledge is arguably just a belief justified in the long run all things considered, and it can be and is revised. Accepting JTB non-vacuously means not only claiming that we got something that will never be revised, but also claiming that we can tell what that is.

Comment: Doesn’t Quine just mean we later discover that we didn’t actually know? All I can say for sure is that there is a long-standing tradition, and current trend, to assume that knowledge implies truth. You don’t need to accept JTB for this, and you don’t need to reject it in order to be a sceptic. If you reject the claim because of doubts about the notion of truth, the debate (to which can can’t contribute anything) should be about the notion of truth, and not about whether knowledge is just JB. Every argument that JTB isn’t sufficient for knowledge is an argument that JB isn’t sufficient.

Comment: @MarkOxford The four intuitions: knowledge is revisable, truth is not revisable, knowledge entails truth, knowledge is transparent (we know that we know) can not all be kept. JTB gives up the fourth, but it means that of things we think we know some we do not, and we do not know which. The more humanly relevant notion then is of what we think we know, without entailment. And since in substance Plato's God's eye view is rejected by Quine, Wittgenstein, etc., they essentially reject JTB. Deflating "truth" to keep it in name only, similar to Quine's "platonism" about math, is JB by another name.

Comment: @conifold I’ve lost track of the proposal. K=JB? OP rejected JTB because of the Gettier cases (I think), but they also disprove K=JB. Is the proposal motivated by some kind of scepticism? What does that sceptic say? That we don’t know anything, that we don’t have any JB’s, that we can’t be sure any of our JB’s are T? Unless everything is T, there’s no way to ‘deflate’ T to a point where JB and JTB are equivalent: JFB’s are K by one account but not the other. I don’t have the intuition that K is revisable, but the linguistic intuition that ‘know’ is factive. - I'm lost!

Comment: @MarkOxford It is just robust fallibilism about knowledge (one might say relativism), the view of many pragmatists and social constructivists, I think. One could say nothing is T in the Plato's classical sense, there are grades, from post-modernist "post-truth" to scientific anti-realism. Truth is treated as a verbal device for asserting beliefs, the focus shifts from truth conditions to assertibility conditions, whatever the latter produce is time/context dependent and defeasible. Since facts are theory, culture, value, etc., laden I suppose "factive" can be kept in name along with revisable.

Comment: Indeed if we don't know what's true, we don't know what we know. But how we know that something is true? By means of other justified (or unjustified ) beliefs or something which is trivially true because of its justification (and refers to our mental state such as "it **seems** to me that there is a blue hat over there"). In the first case our justification doesn't entail truth, while the second is trivial and useless unless we make a stronger claim with a justification which doesn't entail truth (such as "there **is** a blue hat over there" )